# I'm working with text files and I need this:

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text, split

I have string list like this:

```
list1=[354 26 23.02.2013 01:31:24]

list1[0]=3
```

I need:

```
list1[0]=354
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to split your string at the whitespaces. Try the following:

```
splitted_list='354 26 23.02.2013 01:31:24'.split(' ')
print(splitted_list[0]) //Outputs 354
```

Comment: thx this is what i need